# When in Cisco ASA multiple context mode, does each context have a startup and running config?

Tags: cisco-asa

When in Cisco ASA multiple context mode, does each context have a startup and running config? After running `show context`, I would like to understand if I need to run `show run` and `show start`, when wanting to backup the configurations for each context.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as the accepted solution so this question doesn’t continue to come up as unresolved. Alternatively, you can post your own answer and mark that.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to mark yours

Comment: Hahah oh man I am lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. That is the entire purpose of having multiple contexts (also called VDOM (virtual domains) in some devices).  It’s designed for segregating regions (production from non-production, for example) or multi-tenanting a device, and each context is managed independently from the others.

You can read more about multiple security contexts [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa96/configuration/general/asa-96-general-config/ha-contexts.html).